# Animate SKScene background color

Tags: swift, animation, background-color, skscene

I am making a game and I was wondering if you would know how I would go about animating a SKScene background color to fade through random colors on a loop in swift?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using SKScene? If you just want to change the background color you can use a UIView.

Comment: @AntersBear I'm sorry I should have specified that. I'm making a game and I'm using SpriteKit and GameplayKit. Would the code you provided still suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do this in a `UIView`

```
func colorChanges() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1.0)
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        self.colorChanges()
    })
}
```